# Keeping array from POST when using pagination link

Tags: php, post, if-statement, pagination

I am having a litte issue with my searchengine. 
It outputs the searchresult just fine, but when I am clicking a pagination link it fails, of course because it no longer have the `$_POST` array. I am using this piece of code:

```
if(empty($_POST) == false) {

    $res = $search->search_ads($_POST);

    if($res == false) {
       $view->setData('numres', 0);
    } else {
        $view->setData('numres',$res[2]);
        $view->setData('adverts', $res[0]);
   }

   $app->view()->setData('paginate', $res[1]);
   $app->render('search.tpl');
} else {
   $app->render('404.tpl');
}
```

When I click on f.x. "Page 2" it will render the 404 template.

Is there a way I can keep the `$_POST` array and reuse it in the `search_ads` function?

"paginate" contains the HTML for the pagination

```
<li><a class=\"paginate\" href=\"$target?page=$next_page&ipp=$this->items_per_page\">«</a></li>":"<li><span class=\"inactive\" href=\"#\">«</span></li>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use sessions.

```
session_start(); //on the top of your php file.
...

if(!empty($_POST))
   $_SESSION['post_data']= $_POST;
...

if(empty($_SESSION['post_data']) == false) {
$res = $search->search_ads($_SESSION['post_data']);
...

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Store the post array in a variable and use that elsewhere?

```
$post_array = $_POST;
$res = $search->search_ads($post_array);
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to check for **$_GET** rather than $_POST on subsequent pages, as that's the method your using to pass the data:

```
href=\"$target?page=$next_page&ipp=$this->items_per_page\"
```

Will provide you with a $_GET array containing key value pairs:

```
$_GET['page'] = value of $next_page 
$_GET['ipp']  = value of $this->items_per_page
```